# How to compile linux kernel and debug with gcc and BOCHS?

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb

I have download bochs 2.6 sourcecode and installed with gdb-stub configuration. I would like to debug linux-kernel 1.0 or 2.0 or 3.0 which sourcecode downloaded from  http://www.kernel.org/ with gcc and Bochs. How to compiled  the kernel sourcecode and debug it?

Answer (score 2):

Better configure for User Mode (Linux running as a normal user process). BOCHS is painfully slow, and you still have a kernel in charge that you can't look into easily.

BTW, kernels like 1.0 won't manage UM Linux (that came much later), and I don't know if 2.0 handled it either.

If you want simple, you should perhaps look at [Xv6](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2011/xv6.html), a V6 Unix (as in Lyon's book) ported to ANSI C.